# How to ignore validation of some fields with condition in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

I have an OrderRequest with these rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
            'surname' => 'required|max:255',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:255',
            'post_office'=>'required|max:255',
        ];
    }
```

I need to ignore surname and name validation if request has user_id

Currently doing it this way:

```
if ((Input::has('user_id'))) {
            return [
                //
                'city' => 'required|max:255',
                'post_office'=>'required|max:255',
            ];
        }
        return [
            //
            'surname' => 'required|max:255',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:255',
            'post_office'=>'required|max:255',
        ];
    }
```

But can I do it better way and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `user_id` is in your request, you could use `required_without`. Which requires the field under validation to be present and not empty **only** when any of the other specified fields are not present.

```
return [
            //
            'surname' => 'required_without:user_id|max:255',
            'name' => 'required_without:user_id|required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:255',
            'post_office'=>'required|max:255',
        ];
```

So now `surname` and `name` must be present and not empty only when user_id is not present.

---

Also as I said in my comment to Alexey:

Use `Request` instead of `Input` in newer Laravel projects. `Input` is an **alias** for request, they resolve the same dependency from the *service container* but `Input` is nowhere mentioned in the newer Laravel docs and might be removed in the future. Would be unfortunate if you have to replace all `Input` with `request` if you are going to upgrade Laravel ;)

You can either use the `request()` helper function or inject the Helper contract or Facade into the constructor / method.

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Comment: I think required_without is the best solution for my problem. Thanks! (:

Answer (score 3):

I guess using ternary operator and the `request()` helper will be a better way:

```
'surname' => request()->has('user_id') ? '' : 'required|max:255',
```

Comment: I found some information about creating $validator->sometimes(...) in getValidatorInstance. Will it solve my task and if yes isn't it better solution? Or its more complicated and unnecessary than yours?

Comment: Yeah, as Alexey said, use `Request` instead of `Input` in newer Laravel projects. Input is an **alias** for request, they resolve the same dependency from the *service container* but Input is nowhere mentioned in the newer Laravel docs and might be removed in the future. Would be unfortunate if you have to replace all `Input` with `request` if you are going to upgrade Laravel ;)

Comment: You inspire me to `str_replace` all `required` to empty string when using PATCH request.